# Is it possible to filter/ignore objects during the collection phase with java 8 streams?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

This question is related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576386/how-to-use-java-8-streams-groupingby-to-map-multiple-database-records-to-a-singl) I posted a short while ago.

I have figured out a way to group my data the way I want. But because of how I need to group/map the objects I've already closed the stream during collection when I need to apply some filtering. I have the following code:

```
final Map<TeamDetails, List<Player>> teamDetailsPlayerListMap  = 
        dbRows.stream().map(row -> mapDbRowToTeamPlayerPair(row))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TeamPlayerPair::getKey, 
                      Collectors.mapping(TeamPlayerPair::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

final List<Team> teams = teamDetailsPlayerListMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(teamPlayerList -> mapTeamPlayerListToTeam(teamPlayerList))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem I have is that some dbRows have an empty or null `String` for the `playerName`. I don't wan't to filter before collection as if a `Team` has no players (eg. only 1 db row with empty string as player name), I still want to have that in my list of `Team`s at the end. It will just have an empty player list.

Is there any way that I can apply a filter during collection so that empty or null strings will not be added to the list???

I have been able to achieve it with a custom collector as shown below but I'm just wondering if there is a way I can do it without a custom collector???

```
Function<Player, Boolean> emptyPlayerNameFilter = new Function<Player, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Player player) {
         return player != null && player.getName() != null && !"".equals(player.getName());
    }
};

final Map<TeamDetails, List<Player>> teamDetailsPlayerListMap  = 
        dbRows.stream().map(row -> mapDbRowToTeamPlayerPair(row))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TeamPlayerPair::getKey, 
                Collectors.mapping(TeamPlayerPair::getValue, 
                        MyCollectors.toFilteredLinkedList(emptyPlayerNameFilter))));

final List<Team> finalTeams = teamDetailsPlayerListMap.entrySet().stream()
        .map(teamPlayerList -> mapTeamPlayerListToTeam(teamPlayerList))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `MyCollectors.toFilteredLinkedList()` is:

```
public class MyCollectors {

    public static <T, A extends Collection<T>> Collector<T, ?, A> toFilteredCollection(Supplier<A> collectionFactory, Function<T, Boolean> filter) {
        return Collector.of(
                collectionFactory,
                (acc, entry) -> {
                    if (filter.apply(entry)) {
                        acc.add(entry);
                    }
                },
                (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }
        );
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toFilteredLinkedList(Function<T, Boolean> filter) {
        return toFilteredCollection(LinkedList<T>::new, filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that you need a `filtering` collector, which is similar to `mapping`, but performs a filtering. It's already [implemented](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) in Java-9, but absent in Java-8. You can put it into some utility class in your project:

```
public static <T, A, R> Collector<T, A, R> filtering(
        Predicate<? super T> filter, Collector<T, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    Set<Characteristics> characteristics = downstream.characteristics();
    return Collector.of(downstream.supplier(), (acc, t) -> {
        if(filter.test(t)) accumulator.accept(acc, t);
    }, downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(), 
        characteristics.toArray(new Collector.Characteristics[0]));
}
```

And use like this:

```
final Map<TeamDetails, List<Player>> teamDetailsPlayerListMap  = 
    dbRows.stream()
          .map(row -> mapDbRowToTeamPlayerPair(row))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TeamPlayerPair::getKey, 
                Collectors.mapping(TeamPlayerPair::getValue, 
                    filtering(player -> player != null && player.getName() != null 
                                 && !player.getName().isEmpty(), Collectors.toList()))));
```

If you don't like adding `filtering` manually to your project, you may use some third-party library which provides such collector, for example, [`MoreCollectors.filtering()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-), which is available in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library.